# How to show all errors in one place? A navigation window for "x error found"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

[image]

On the right, we can see something going on, and after it is done, it shows "x error found". 
What is this exactly? Java compiler? Lint tool? Build-in analysis?

The problem is, when file gets large, it is hard to find out where the error is.

I know we can use F2 to navigate, but it also navigates to warnings. It would be nice to have a window showing all the errors in one place. Where is the navigation window for "x error found"?

Thanks for Vucko's answer. I didn't know it is clickable. Really appreciate it. But, I have to click that, hover my mouse over the codes, then wait for the error details to pop up, which costs lots of time. Also, warning is clickable, which is annoying. I still prefer a window.

Comment: F2 will only jump to/between errors when errors are present. It only toggles between warnings if there are no errors present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Figured it out by myself.

After we Build > Make Project, Messages window pops up. All the errors show up here. We can click on each error to navigate to the corresponding file and location, or copy it to search on Google.

It is most likely Java compiler. Somehow it compiles on the fly. But, sometimes it is not reliable just like Instant Run is not reliable. If it becomes inconsistent with Messages window, try to restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind how big the file is, you can simply find the error by clicking the horizontal **red line** below. Every error will have it's own line and by clicking on it, you will be taken to that line immediately.

See the image for better understanding of what I mean:

[image: The image]

> Note: This is quite a useful tool for some other stuff as well, for example warnings will be shown and colored in orange (every color is customizable of course), and if you're using version control, e.g. Git, your changes will be colored in blue/green for edits/additions respectively.

Comment: Thanks man. I didn't know it is clickable. Upvote. But, I have to click that, hover my mouse over the codes, then wait for the error details to pop up, which costs lots of time. Also, warning is clickable, which is annoying. I still prefer a window like Messages window or Inspection window.

Comment: I do not know about you, but I love tha feature. I am using Android Studio and PHPStorm, both based on IntelliJ, and the moment I err, it shows (no waiting needed). There probably is what you're looking for, I'll see when I get to my laptop and write to ya if I find anything.

Answer (score 1):

> I know we can use F2 to navigate, but it also navigates to warnings.

You can right-click on the scrollbar and select this option.
[Go to high priority problems only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPHqv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried filtering Logcat to Error? Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Analyze --> Inspect code this will give you all your error with line number. it will even show typo

[image]